# How to create custom shortcut to delete file permanently?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

My <kbd>delete</kbd> key does not work. So, I always have to right click on a file to delete it. So, I wanted to create custom shortcut to delete a file permanently.

I want to add <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> as my custom shortcut. In the *Add Custom Shortcut Dialog Box*, I fill up name and shortcut field and in command field I write `rm -rf`, which doesn't work. I know I have to specify file address in the command but, I don't get what to write.

What is the correct command for deleting a file permanently?

Comment: Maybe something like this might work for you:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/xkb-make-ctrlbackspace-behave-as-delete

Comment: Bear in mind that shortcuts defined by _Add Custom Shortcut_ dialog box are **desktop-wide**. That means they will work in any window, not only in file manager. So you can't use a file name as parameter, because it's not known if there will be any file name defined at all (for example when you're in the web browser window). What you would need is a way to create a custom keyboard shortcut **within** Nautilus file manager. However, as far as I know, Nautilus does not support that.